# Connecting an android App to ESP8266 programmatically

Tags: android, esp8266

we're trying to connect our ESP8266 to android application on device with android version 6+ , the app is to programmatically connect to esp8266 access point to send and receive some commands using http requests, the app works fine with android version below 6, the app on some phones using android 6 and above does work fine, others phones don't work at all (aka not connecting to the esp) .the app configures the network properly but the phone doesn't connect to it programmatically but it connects to it if you choose it from wifi in settings without asking for passkey (which means that the network is configured correctly).
Edit : The Phones that usually don't work , can work when you delete the other available configured networks , thus leaving only the ESP configured Network to connect to

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static int ids;
    private static AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager1;
    static SharedPreferences credentials;
    static RemoteViews rv;

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Log.i("Scenario","onEnabled");
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
        ids=0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
        ids-=1;
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {
        Log.i("lastLog","updateAppWidget");
        ids=appWidgetId;
        appWidgetManager1=appWidgetManager;


        rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

/*   do stuff 
*/
     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ids, rv);


    }

    public static PendingIntent getSelfPendingIntent(Context context, String command){
        Log.i("lastLog","getSelfPendingIntent");
        Intent actionPerformed = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
        actionPerformed.setAction(command);
        actionPerformed.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionPerformed, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.i("lastLog", "onUpdate");
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("lastLog","onReceive: "+intent.getAction().toString());
        String passKey=intent.getAction().toString() + context.getSharedPreferences("PassKey", 0);

        credentials = context.getSharedPreferences("MainStorage", 0);
        rv= new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        if (intent.getAction().toString().equals("OPEN")){
            opened=true;
        }
        else{
            opened=false;
        }
//      updating the widget's layout drawing
        if (appWidgetManager1!=null)
        {updateAppWidget(context,appWidgetManager1, ids);}
//       end of layout drawing update

        wifi_action(context, intent);

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
    public void wifi_action(final Context context, Intent intent){

        //       start sending the HTTP REQUEST
        if (intent.getAction().toString().equals("somthing") || intent.getAction().toString().equals("somtthingelse")){
            Log.i("lastLog","1");
            final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

            String storedSSID=credentials.getString("SSID","");
            String storedNetworkPass=credentials.getString("NetworkPassword","");
            String storedPassKey=credentials.getString("PassKey","");
            String storedUrl=credentials.getString("URL","")+storedPassKey+intent.getAction().toString();
            Log.i("lastLog","2");
//            Log.i("SSID",storedSSID);
//            Log.i("Network Password",storedNetworkPass);
//            Log.i("Action PassKey",storedPassKey);
//            Log.i("URL",storedUrl);

            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                while(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
            }
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                while (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
            }
            Log.i("lastLog","3");
            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                WifiConfiguration configuration= new WifiConfiguration();
                configuration.SSID="\"" + "SSID" + "\"";
                configuration.preSharedKey="\""+ "somepass"  + "\"";
                wifiManager.addNetwork(configuration);

                List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

                Log.i("lastLog","4");
                for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
                    Log.i("lastLog",i.SSID);
                    if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + "SSID" + "\"")) {
                        Log.i("lastLog", "Network Found, #"+i);
                        wifiManager.disconnect();
                        wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                        wifiManager.reconnect();
                        Log.i("lastLog", "supposed to be connected by now");
                        client.get(context, "http://somelink", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                                for (int i = 1; i < ids; i++) {
                                    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager1, ids);
                                    Log.i("lastLog", "Command Communicated Successfully!");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                                Log.i("lastLog", "Command Communicated Failed");
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        if  (intent.getAction().equals("SETTINGS")){
            Intent startSettings = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(startSettings);
        }
    }
}
```